# ShareActionProvider gives error with Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-theme, shareactionprovider

I want actionbar share provider in one of my activities, and i have Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar as baseTheme.

Here is how i create share option on activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    ShareActionProvider provider = new ShareActionProvider(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    provider.setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
    provider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, SHARE_ACTION_ID, 0,
            getString(R.string.action_share))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon_share_white)
            .setActionProvider(provider)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
    return shareIntent;
}
```

And this is my baseTheme:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.    

    -->
</style> 

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. --> 
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/action_item_background_selector</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/action_item_background_selector</item>
</style>
```

App works just fine with Theme.Sherlock but when i use my AppTheme it gives me this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1026)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:671)
at com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider.onCreateActionView(ShareActionProvider.java:170)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.ActionProviderWrapper.onCreateActionView(ActionProviderWrapper.java:23)
at android.view.ActionProvider.onCreateActionView(ActionProvider.java:98)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:580)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:264)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:555)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1048)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:91)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:297)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:244)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:946)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:969)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:498)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:3192)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've seen lots of this kind of questions and their accepted responses but no luck.. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** 
Removing "actionBarItemBackground" these attributes from AppTheme in style.xml also works, but i need actionbar to have a custom background as well... So what could be the solution for that?

Comment: What does the third parameter of menu.add() do?

Comment: It is "order", but not relavent with problem.

Comment: You are right, just another guess do you use the right ShareActionProvider implementation? There is also a native and a compat implementation.

Comment: Yeah, i use this one: "com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider"

Comment: Dammed Mondays I give up

Comment: Agreed! Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 reputation to comment so I'll answer it here.

This error:

```
Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

tells you that a style, or `parent` directive of a style cannot be resolved by Android at runtime. Check your **styles.xml** file again.

If you are using Eclipse, you can check the correctness of the `name`, `parent`, etc directives by pressing Left-click, or Ctrl+Left-click on each of the directive. If the clicked value is resolved, Eclipse will either move to another area within `styles.xml`, or open up a new stylesheet file.

**UPDATE 1:**

@yahya: *"i use AppBase theme... so it works almost every activity but not just this one"* Post the codes of the activity that's not working. Also, post your **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

Comment: Thanks but i use AppBase theme -you can see on question- as base theme, so it works almost every activity but not just this one. And when i change this activity's theme to Theme.Sherlock it works just fine...